# ASP.NET Core 3.0 app not working on Windows Server 2012 R2 due to ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, https, windows-server-2012-r2, network-protocols

I took a working ASP.NET Core 2.2 app, upgraded it to 3.0 and suddenly the app no longer works in Windows Server 2012. It comes up with the following:

`ERR_HTTP2_INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY`

Chrome:
[image]

Firefox:
[image]

It seems that before I had to opt into HTTP/2 and now its the default along with HTTP1.1. There is a post here `https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14350` but that is totally confusing with no real solution.

I have tried all sorts of enabling / disabling insecure protocols but to no avail. Such as https://www.admin-enclave.com/de/articles-by-year/11-data-articles/website_articles/articles/exchange_articles/405-resolved-error-err_spdy_inadequate_transport_security-when-using-google-chome-and-owa.html

Works fine on Windows 10 due to what I assume more better protocol suite. But in Fiddler I checked and the only difference when negotiating with Kestrel is:

Windows Server 2012 R2:

```
[0A0A]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[1301]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[1302]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[1303]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[C02F]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[C030]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[CCA9]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[CCA8]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[009C]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[009D]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
[0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
[000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
```

Windows 10:

```
[3A3A]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[1301]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[1302]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[1303]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[C02B]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
[C02F]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[C02C]  TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
[C030]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[CCA9]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[CCA8]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
[C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
[009C]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[009D]  Unrecognized cipher - See http://www.iana.org/assignments/tls-parameters/
[002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
[0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
[000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
```

The top line is different, but that is all. Not sure what is it, it is some `GREASE` value.

Program.cs:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
      WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
      .UseKestrel(opts => {
        opts.ListenAnyIP(5000);
        opts.ListenAnyIP(5001, listenOpts => {
          listenOpts.UseHttps(new HttpsConnectionAdapterOptions {
            ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2("certificate-server.pfx", "...")
          });
        });
        opts.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = null;
      })
      .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .UseStartup<Startup>();
  }
```

## Update

Seems I am on the right track thanks to @chris-pratt. Changing the certificate cipher to `ECDSA_nistP256` make the web application work. But unfortunately I am using the cert to also sign the JWT tokens, and now that is broken with:

> System.NotSupportedException: The certificate key algorithm is not
>   supported. at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.PublicKey.get_Key()

The signing code is:

```
  var privateKey = new X509SecurityKey(new X509Certificate2("certificate-server.pfx", "..."));
  var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
    issuer: "Sentry",
    claims: claims,
    notBefore: DateTime.Now,
    expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(privateKey, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature));

  return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
```

I tried changing the `SecurityAlgorithms` enum but did not get any success.

Comment: Do you have any ASP.NET Core 3.0 applications that do run on that server? I am thinking that you may need to add Roles/Features to the server through the server manager.

Comment: @kristech yes this same app used to run fine until I made a new version with .NET Core 3.0

Comment: In the Server Manager, click on Add Roles and features. In the Server Roles Section go to Web Server (IIS) > Web Server > Security. Install all of those roles in that section. Restart the server afterwards and then try again.

Comment: @kristech even though I am self hosting using Kestrel I tried your suggestion, but it did not work.

Comment: What cipher suite is the cert using?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Its a self signed certificate I created using powershell using command `New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName localhost -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(120) -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My`, how do I find out the cipher suite being used?

Comment: @ChrisPratt IE 11 is reporting the connection as "TLS 1.2, AES with 128 bit encryption (High); RSA with 2048 bit exchange"

Comment: The default cipher suite for Windows doesn't cover HTTP/2. Try regenerating it with the -AlternateSignatureAlgorithm param.

Comment: @ChrisPratt That still makes a similar cert, (I need to deploy it to test it though). How about `-KeyAlgorithm ECDSA_nistP256` seems promising?

Comment: Similar, but with a slightly more secure cipher. Not sure if that's enough, but give it a try. I don't use PowerShell to gen certs, so I'm working off the docs.

Comment: @ChrisPratt the `-AlternateSignatureAlgorithm` gives the same error, and `-KeyAlgorithm ECDSA_nistP256` kind of works, loads the login page, however fails on the signing of the JWT token (with the same cert) with error `The certificate key algorithm is not supported`.

Comment: any development with this?

Comment: Using Blazor on Kestrel with official Letsencrypt certificates seems to fail too with NS_ERROR_NET_INADEQUATE_SECURITY. Of course I can not make any adjustments to the certificate to work around this issue. Absolute showstopper!

Answer (score 4):

Windows 2012 R2 does not support the cypher suites that are allowed for HTTP/2. I assume that starting with Core 3.0 the HTTP/2 protocol is enabled by default. I solved my problem by disabling HTTP/2 in kestrel as follows:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>

  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
  {
      webBuilder.UseKestrel(options =>
      {
        options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(DomainIp), 80);
        options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(DomainIp), 443, l =>
        {
          l.UseHttps(
            DomainCertificateFile,
            DomainCertificatePassword);
          l.Protocols = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.HttpProtocols.Http1;
        });
      });
      webBuilder.UseStaticWebAssets();
      webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
   });
```

Comment: This works for me, but this has consequences. My api itself makes outband https GET requests that fail due to https negotiation errors

Comment: @baouss In my Blazor project I use outbound HTTPS calls with the HttpClient. This works with Http1 (on W2012 Server) and Http2 (on Windows 10).

Comment: Thx for the confirmation of it working on that setup. I just realised today, that TLS 1.2 is disabled in the machine's registry but the service I'm calling requires it.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add further info that may be useful for others. In the case of IIS HTTP/2 support starts from Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016. See: [HTTP/2 on IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10/http2-on-iis)

However, you may encounter this problem in Windows 10 as well. In this case be advised to make sure if disabling HTTP/2 is really what you're looking for, especially with regards to security concerns. Let's refer to the [GitHub thread](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/14350) the OP mentioned:

> "This disables HTTP/2, and the "INADEQUATE_TRANSPORT_SECURITY" issue
>   is an HTTP/2-specific issue, so while that works, it's not really a
>   solution".

Source: [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14350#issuecomment-540128744)

To resolve this problem occurring under Windows 10, what is advised in the first place is making sure whether SSL Cipher Suite Order is correct.

> To configure the SSL Cipher Suite Order group policy setting:
>
> 1. At a command prompt, enter **gpedit.msc**. The **Group Policy Object Editor** appears.
> 2. Expand **Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Network**, and then click **SSL Configuration Settings**.
> 3. Under **SSL Configuration Settings**, click the **SSL Cipher Suite Order** setting.
> 4. In the **SSL Cipher Suite Order** pane, scroll to the bottom of the pane.
> 5. Follow the instructions labelled **How to modify this setting**.

See: [Prioritizing Schannel Cipher Suites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/prioritizing-schannel-cipher-suites)

[image: Cipher Suite Order]

It may differ from default one and cause problems. Or if the default one causes problems, this is a place you can adjust it.

> To circle back to the original issue. @hristijankiko sent us some
>   great details (including a Wireshark trace that was very helpful). We
>   identified that the server was selecting a cipher suite on the HTTP/2
>   block-list due to "inadequate security". It turns out this was a
>   machine-level configuration issue caused by upgrading from earlier
>   Windows versions. The fix was to manually configure the TLS cipher
>   suites to match the new Windows 10 defaults
>   (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-10-v1903).
>   It's curious that this was necessary even though @hristijankiko was
>   using Windows 10 v1903 but we will check in on this internall. No
>   further action on the original issue is needed in ASP.NET Core.

Source: [further GitHub disscussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14350#issuecomment-542317393)

Here you can check which TLS cipher suites and priority order are supported by a given Windows version:

[Cipher Suites in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/cipher-suites-in-schannel)

For both Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows 8.1 supported cipher suites see:

[TLS Cipher Suites in Windows 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/tls-cipher-suites-in-windows-8-1)

You can have a quick look at a selected cipher under security tab of developer tools:
[image: Security tab of developer tools]

Comment: Worked for me, a restart is required after applying the settings